# Responsive carousel gallery

Tags: html

My image carousel gallery isn't responsive which it should be, can someone help?

```
<div id="scroller" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0 auto;">
    <div class="innerScrollArea">
        <ul>
            <li><img src="img/gallery/image1.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="img/gallery/image2.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="img/gallery/image3.jpg" /></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

The images should resize according to the device that it is being displayed on e.g. tablet or phone but they don't resize which ruins my site which is responsive, thanks in advance.

Comment: What carousel, what JS lib are you using for carousel... too "much" info to understand the issue.

Comment: Hi, I am using jQuery.